Project cannot start when reading keys from .env file
The system is Windows11 ( for the development of the project ).
In the application.properties there are references to keys of a .env file which is located on the root folder of the project :
application.properties :
app.version=@project.version@
api.url = ${APP_API_URL}
api.site.url = ${APP_SITE_URL}/api
signup.url = ${APP_SITE_URL}

server.port=9000

BALANCE_PLATFORM_API_KEY = ${ADYEN_BALANCE_PLATFORM_API_KEY}
BALANCE_PLATFORM = Multimicro
SCOPE_COMPANY_KEY = ${ADYEN_SCOPE_COMPANY_KEY}
ONBOARDING = ${ADYEN_ONBOARDING}

thermal.printer.url = ${APP_PRINT_URL}


ADYEN_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT=MultimicroECOM   
ADYEN_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT_POS=MultimicroPOS
HMAC_KEY=ieruoweriugdfkjgwoieruh 

ADYEN_API_KEY=${ADYEN_API_KEY}
KEY_TERMINAL=${ADYEN_KEY_TERMINAL}

the .env file :
APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000/api
APP_SITE_URL=http://localhost:7000/api
ADYEN_BALANCE_PLATFORM_API_KEY=AQE0hmfxJorGbBBCw0ixnmU2pOGrRIpZC5xYVSt703S/l2tCndV593sKXCu5xgXDNJ49YvvXeRDBXVsNvuR83LVYjEgiTGAH-RTfKXigvYhOkCNqt/beyhhj+Ua2cIDLxXv+OjBr/b0E=-8HK}[KvQ)<Q%%=hQ
ADYEN_SCOPE_COMPANY_KEY = AQEyhmfxKYjPaBxFw1mznXQ96ceURZtMA4p1dXBa0nGml2VZkTuQOBID/JW0OqJo9lyYXX8QwV1bDb7kfNy1WIxIIkxgBw==-IEWOvIxf76rN+RRPZp8jEzDXHH+eQX5CWkxtHt9QYaI=-~}2y^XLzsm6e8gDq
ADYEN_ONBOARDING=ONBT422JV223224T5JWN6NN55G2THF
APP_PRINT_URL=http://localhost:5000
ADYEN_API_KEY=AQEshmfxLYnMbxNFw0m/n3Q5qf3VZZ5BGZpHUWZEyVyGZVU6i/zTs9/RFhFFItcQwV1bDb7kfNy1WIxIIkxgBw==-HQJWKhwnsPiRuKYE9fuMQ7sJhWxeIO0O11RyirK5Vmw=-xTy}.Tk5~)g>ZC@S
ADYEN_KEY_TERMINAL=AQEshmfxLonPbhdAw0m/n3Q5qf3VZZ5BGZpHUWZEycwmaIP0kqHo35UJAG9zgAMQwV1bDb7kfNy1WIxIIkxgBw==-iO75bqUlM12NVqjnnChweWrDIp0M8SfYKe8TFvvOOdk=-KY_5.>a=Dw4#_sHT
APP_FRONT_URL=http://localhost:8080

When I run the project then I get this on the terminal :
PS C:\Projets\MAT V2>  & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe' '@C:\Users\andy\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_5s8gfzxhmneufsrwjzfgbhzwn.argfile' 'com.fnptechnologies.backend.BackendApplication' 

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)

2024-06-20T15:33:39.278+03:00  INFO 12820 --- [  restartedMain] c.f.backend.BackendApplication           : Starting BackendApplication using Java 17.0.10 with PID 12820 (C:\Projets\MAT V2\backend-ui\target\classes started by andy in C:\Projets\MAT V2)
2024-06-20T15:33:39.281+03:00  INFO 12820 --- [  restartedMain] c.f.backend.BackendApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-06-20T15:33:39.363+03:00  INFO 12820 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-06-20T15:33:39.366+03:00  INFO 12820 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2024-06-20T15:33:41.384+03:00  INFO 12820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9000 (http)
2024-06-20T15:33:41.419+03:00  INFO 12820 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-06-20T15:33:41.420+03:00  INFO 12820 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
2024-06-20T15:33:41.595+03:00  INFO 12820 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-06-20T15:33:41.595+03:00  INFO 12820 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2228 ms
2024-06-20T15:33:41.717+03:00  WARN 12820 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
2024-06-20T15:33:41.722+03:00  INFO 12820 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]      
2024-06-20T15:33:41.758+03:00  INFO 12820 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-06-20T15:33:41.801+03:00 ERROR 12820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at com.fnptechnologies.backend.BackendApplication.main(BackendApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2] 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'APP_API_URL' in value "${APP_API_URL}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:230) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:79) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:60) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:552) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]    
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:153) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:149) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:74) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:153) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:191) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:920) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:696) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:483) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        ... 22 common frames omitted

PS C:\Projets\MAT V2> 

So how to fix it ?

What happend when you set the evironment variables manually? Does this work?
I think spring boot will not load the variables from the .env file automatically. The variables must exist when the application starts. You have multiple possibilities to set them or load the .env file:

Set them manually
Load .env file via maven dependency: https://github.com/paulschwarz/spring-dotenv
Load .env file via external script
Set environment variables inside runtime environment for example when you are using docker images/container

Regards




What happend when you set the evironment variables manually? Does this work?



yes it works when I set the property-values manually in the application.properties file

No, i mean when you set the enviroment variables inside manually. Open a terminal, set the environment variables (with the set - command), start the spring application with that terminal window to make sure that the variables where correctly set. But anyway i think there is no automation inside spring to load .env file.
